# Rectilinearize a non-intersecting polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I have some non-intersecting polygon, and I need to "square" it up so that all angles are 90 degree angles.

Is there a good algorithm to do this?

*EDIT*

Allowing self-intersections in the resultant polygon, I'm looking for the "best" method of tesselating rectangular shaped tiles in the original polygon. The rectangles can span the original edges of the polygon, and the goal is to fit the most rectangles squarely into the polygon.

Comment: I don't think a general algorithm exists for all polygons. For example, how do you make a triangle have all 90 degree angles, without adding any new sides?

Comment: How many sides are you willing to add? If there's no limit, you can replace the diagonal sides in your original polygon with sawtooth-like sequences of sides, and get a good approximation of the original, in terms of total area and position of original vertices.

Comment: At most, 1 side per original side. The output needs to be rectilinear and minimum bounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace each side of the polygon with a "staircase" which resembles the original side, like so:

[image: sawtooth algorithm output]

the more "steps" you add to each staircase, the closer it resembles the original shape.

Comment: What if I want the tightest fit with a maximum of 1 step per original side?

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that you can avoid self-intersections if you allow just one new segment per original segment.

You can use a quadtree to subdivide the line segments until each line segment is alone in its quadtree cell (alternatively you can subdivide further until some approximation ratio is reached). Then replace each line-segment by two line segments of its bounding box.

hth

Comment: Can you post a picture? I see what you mean about avoiding self-intersections. I think that is acceptable for my problem. I'm looking for the "best" method of tesselating rectangular shaped tiles in a polygon. The rectangles can span the original edges of the polygon, and the goal is to fit the most rectangles squarely into the polygon.

Comment: Search in Google Pics for "polygon quadtree". One that I've found is: http://www.emeraldinsight.com/content_images/fig/1560120405015.png

Comment: I am not working with curves. All sides of my polygons are straight.